# Is there a combined achievements / leaderboard Intent

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I incorporated both achievements and leaderboards into my game, but I can't find a way to show them both with a single button press. I know there is

```
Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(getApiClient());
```

to show a leaderboard UI and there is

```
Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(getApiClient())
```

But is there also an intent where the user can see her full record of both leaderboards and achievements?

Answer (score 2):

No there is not. It is not possible. But you can make your own custom UI. Be aware if you do so that you can't really retrieve scores and rankings for all your leadeboards, so you would only be able to display leaderboards metadata, like name, picture, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this within your own app, however if the user has the Play Games app installed he/she can see a unified view of Leaderboards and Achievements in that app.